# Sandboxを有効にしたときのrealmファイルの開き方について教えてください

Tags: swift, macos, realm

Sandboxを有効にしたとき、OpenPanelから選択したrealmファイルを開くと [realmファイル].realm.managementフォルダの作成時に例外が起きます。
回避する方法を教えてください。
realmファイルはユーザがOpenPanelで選択可能な場所に存在することを想定しています。

Answer (score 0):

プロジェクト設定の、`Capabilities`タブの`App Sandboxing`の下の方に`File Access`という蘭が有ると思うのですが、そこの`User Selected File`を`Read/Write`にするとどうなりますか？

Comment: Read/Writeに設定しています。新規にrealmファイルを作成する場合は、まずフォルダーを選択し、ファイル名を指定するUIにしています。その場合には書き込みはできています。既に作成されたファイルに対し更新する場合には、OpenPanelでファイルを選択するUIを考えているのですが、いまの有様です。

Answer (score 0):

Open Panelから選択したrealmファイルを更新モードで使用することは諦めました。
その代わり、まず読み書きの許可を与えるためOpen Panelでディレクトリを選択し、それからそのディレクトリ下のrealmファイルを選択するUIに変更することにしました。
あと、アプリ終了時にはrealm関連ファイル(lock, note, management)を削除することにしました。